# BlueSnap integration with node js and angular

Tags: bluesnap

Need guidance to integrate the Bluesnap Payment gateway with nodejs and angular. As per developer Hub of bluesnap the on button submit the submitCredentials should be sent to bluesnap server and bluesnap server will sent back the card data. But i am not getting the response as stated in developer guide. When i sent the data to server in xml format then response i  get is unautorization access.

Step 1 am Following is Get token from the server sample respose i am printing
{ response: 
   { debugId: 2,
     headers: 
      { date: 'Tue, 14 Jun 2016 07:23:59 GMT',
        server: 'BlueSnap-UK',
        'set-cookie': [Object],
        location: 'https://ws.bluesnap.com/services/2/payment-fields-tokens/a55d11bc16322318f3cabf39b66e698e1f2087327bc03edb960c6f519f3681f2_2',
        'content-length': '0',
        'keep-alive': 'timeout=2, max=80',
        connection: 'Keep-Alive',
        'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
        f5: '/Common/web-vlan20-https 10.11.20.15%20 443',
        'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains' },
     statusCode: 201,
     body: '' } }
In the header location i am getting the token

Step 2 : Need to encrypt the sensative field and javascript is given by bluesnap to do that.

Step 3. need to submit the details to bluesnap server with token. and server will response with carddata
Step 4. Need to give server to server call to https://ws.bluesnap.com/services/2/transactions where i am receiving unautorize or status code 403
Please guide me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your setup and some roles are missing, you need to contact Bluesnap support or Onboarding and ask for the correct permissions to be granted in Production.

If you is still in development mode you should test against the Sandbox where you have the correct permissions.

Can you send your payment page example. I think you are not calling bluesnap.submitCredentials function correctly.

Thanks